# Entity Date property: Cannot format given Object as a Date

Tags: java, type-conversion

I've an entity Date property:

```
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
private Date paymentDate;
```

that I've to convert to a String. Using the following code I receive the *Cannot format given Object as a Date* exception:

```
Format df = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
String pDate = df.format(item.getPaymentDate());
```

Where I wrong?

Comment: Post the code for `getPaymentDate`

Comment: Check the import Date line. Is it java.util.Date?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Format#format(Object)` method delegates to a sub type's `format(Object, StringBuffer, FieldPosition)` method. The `DateFormat` implementation which `SimpleDateFormat` inherits is as follows

```
public final StringBuffer format(Object obj, StringBuffer toAppendTo, FieldPosition fieldPosition)
{
    if (obj instanceof Date)
        return format( (Date)obj, toAppendTo, fieldPosition );
    else if (obj instanceof Number)
        return format( new Date(((Number)obj).longValue()), toAppendTo, fieldPosition );
    else
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Cannot format given Object as a Date");
}
```

In other words, the value returned by `item.getPaymentDate()` must either be `null` or be of a type other than `java.util.Date` or `java.lang.Number`.

Comment: Thanks. You are ready not all item.getPaymentDate() contains date, some can be null.

Comment: @enrico You're welcome. You should probably just perform a `null` check before trying to format.